# How to run shell script via terminal

Tags: command-line, 13.04, scripts

I just upgraded to 13.04. Before this when I click on a shell script file it'll give an option to run via terminal but now the option is no longer available and when I click the file it'll directly open via gedit.

How to run it via terminal and if possible, make it like that on default?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the file explorer `Files`. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and select `Preferences`. You should see something like this.

In the `Behavior` tab, select `Ask each time` and close it. Now double on a shell script will ask you what to do each time. If you want to straight away execute the script, select the first option `Run executable text files when they are opened`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Open up a terminal and change to the dir that the script is in and type

> ./scriptname